# Accessing an object's content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to Javascript. I just have a basic question. Can somebody tell me why executing the javascript code in the JSFiddle link below results in this error:" Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null".

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/ali89ma/tz5h8umk

```
var myTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
var row1 = myTable.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row1.insertCell(-1);
cell1.innerHTML = "23.00";
cell1.id = "1000price";
var cell1Content = document.getElementById("1000price").innerHTML;
console.log(cell1Content);
```

But if I write the line below it works fine.

```
var cell1Content = cell1.innerHTML;
console.log(cell1Content);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should do "document.body.appendChild(myTable);" before getting your element by id for adding your html-element do document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned above The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute **from the DOM** with the specified value.

you create a table element dynamiclly but you didnt append it to your page(this will add the table to the DOM elements)

so you need to add this append order to your code like that :

```
// create a table element dynamiccly but it still not in the DOM elements
    var myTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
    var row1 = myTable.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row1.insertCell(-1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "23.00";
    cell1.id = "1000price";
//the next line will add your table to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild( myTable );
//now you can use the getElementById method to get elements from the DOM
    var cell1Content = document.getElementById("1000price").innerHTML;
    console.log(cell1Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

`insertCell` returns `null` if the parent `table` does not exist in the DOM.

Add this line immediately after line 1:

```
var myTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
document.body.appendChild( myTable ); // <-- this line
var row1 = myTable.insertRow(-1);
```

After adding the line it works and I get "23.00" output in my console.

Answer (score 0):

You must append element after create

```
var myTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
document.body.appendChild(myTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the table through javascript. When you are trying to access the table element it will not be present in the DOM. You need to add the table to the DOM then it will work. Add this line able the var cell1Content

document.body.append(myTable);

Answer (score 0):

append table in `body` before accessing element

```
var myTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
document.body.appendChild(myTable);
```

working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tz5h8umk/2/